# How to select an object from an array by id?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object that contains an array called applicants:

```
const persons={"entities":{"applicants":[{"lastName":"Agamemnon","isPrimaryApplicant":false,"id":"16671520038"},{"lastName":"Purdy","isPrimaryApplicant":true,"id":"16671520039"},{"lastName":"Brekky","isPrimaryApplicant":true,"id":"16671520040"},{"lastName":"Abouli","isPrimaryApplicant":true,"id":"16671520041"}]}}
```

How can I return the item from the entities.applicants array by id?

I tried something like:

```
const applicantsById = persons.entities.applicants.find(a => a.id ===id)

console.log(applicantsById.get('16671520041'))
```

But I can't figure out how to pass in the id?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/bertie2017/pen/RvPzbg?editors=0012)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **vanilla javascript**:

You need to define what `id` is before you set your `applicantsById` variable. This way you can find an `id` in your array of objects which equals the `id` you defined.

```
const id = '16671520041';
const applicantsById = persons.entities.applicants.find(a => a.id === id);
```

You can extend this to a function if you wish to use this with multiple ids:

```js
const persons = {"entities":{"applicants":[{"lastName":"Agamemnon","isPrimaryApplicant":false,"id":"16671520038"},{"lastName":"Purdy","isPrimaryApplicant":true,"id":"16671520039"},{"lastName":"Brekky","isPrimaryApplicant":true,"id":"16671520040"},{"lastName":"Abouli","isPrimaryApplicant":true,"id":"16671520041"}]}};
const getApplicantById = _id => persons.entities.applicants.find(({id}) => id === _id);

console.log(getApplicantById('16671520041')); // Abouli obj
console.log(getApplicantById('16671520039')); // Purdy obj
```

Or, using **Lodash and ES6**:

```js
const persons = {"entities":{"applicants":[{"lastName":"Agamemnon","isPrimaryApplicant":false,"id":"16671520038"},{"lastName":"Purdy","isPrimaryApplicant":true,"id":"16671520039"},{"lastName":"Brekky","isPrimaryApplicant":true,"id":"16671520040"},{"lastName":"Abouli","isPrimaryApplicant":true,"id":"16671520041"}]}};

const id = "16671520041";
const res = _.find(persons.entities.applicants, {id}); 
console.log(res); // Abouli obj
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`applicantsById` needs to be a function parametrized on the id

```js
const persons={"entities":{"applicants":[{"lastName":"Agamemnon","isPrimaryApplicant":false,"id":"16671520038"},{"lastName":"Purdy","isPrimaryApplicant":true,"id":"16671520039"},{"lastName":"Brekky","isPrimaryApplicant":true,"id":"16671520040"},{"lastName":"Abouli","isPrimaryApplicant":true,"id":"16671520041"}]}}

const applicantsById = id => persons.entities.applicants.find(a => a.id ===id)
console.log(applicantsById('16671520041'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use filter for this

```js
const persons={"entities":{"applicants":[{"lastName":"Agamemnon","isPrimaryApplicant":false,"id":"16671520038"},{"lastName":"Purdy","isPrimaryApplicant":true,"id":"16671520039"},{"lastName":"Brekky","isPrimaryApplicant":true,"id":"16671520040"},{"lastName":"Abouli","isPrimaryApplicant":true,"id":"16671520041"}]}}

console.log(get(16671520039));

function get(id)
{
return persons.entities.applicants.filter((e)=>e.id===id)
}
```

Comment: `find` is the better option.

Comment: PS. I'd also be wary about mixing types like that, and use strict equality `===` whereever possible. Saves on bugs down the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can either define your id before you do your `find`:

```
const id = '16671520041';
const applicantsById = persons.entities.applicants.find(a => a.id ===id)
```

Or you can define a function that accepts an id as an argument. The other answers have covered how to do this with modern ES6 arrow functions. If you're unfamiliar with them here's the ES5 function declaration-way of writing it. Here I've also passed in the persons data to the function.

```js
const persons={"entities":{"applicants":[{"lastName":"Agamemnon","isPrimaryApplicant":false,"id":"16671520038"},{"lastName":"Purdy","isPrimaryApplicant":true,"id":"16671520039"},{"lastName":"Brekky","isPrimaryApplicant":true,"id":"16671520040"},{"lastName":"Abouli","isPrimaryApplicant":true,"id":"16671520041"}]}}

// Accept persons data, and an id
function getApplicantById(persons, id) {

  // Return the found applicant from the function
  return persons.entities.applicants.find(a => a.id ===id);
}

// Pass in the data, and the id to the function
const applicant = getApplicantById(persons, '16671520041');
console.log(applicant);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function.

```
const applicantsById = (id) => persons.entities.applicants.find(a => a.id === id)
applicantsById('16671520041')
```

this will return you required result